# How to create array of sprites?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to this cocos2dx from last 3 days I am trying to create array of sprites suppose lets take I have 1.png ,2.png, 3.png, 4.png sprites and I need to store in an array in such way that while `addchild()` the sprites should appear randomly on the screen please let me know the code?

```
std::vector<std::string> _spriteNames = {"0.png", "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"};
for (int i=0;i < _spriteNames.size(); i++) {
  CCSprite* foo = cocos2d::CCSprite::create(_spriteNames.at(i));  //here i am getting error as no matching of the function??
  int random = rand() % 5;
  foo->setPosition(CCPoint((60 * random), (50 * random)));
  _sprites.push_back(foo); 
  addChild(foo, 1); 
}
```

Comment: Does `create` have an overload that accepts a `std::string`?

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Also, I answered this and gave you this code. Why didn't you reply back to the original post located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491659/how-to-create-random-sprites/23499031#23499031

```
std::vector<CCSprite*> _sprites;
std::vector<std::string> _spriteNames = {"0.png", "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"};

for (int i=0;i < _spriteNames.size(); i++)
{
    CCSprite* foo = cocos2d::CCSprite::create(_spriteNames.at(i));//here i am getting error as no matching of the function??

    int random = rand() % 5;

    foo->setPosition(CCPoint((60 * random), (50 * random)));

    _sprites.push_back(foo);

    addChild(foo, 1);
}
```

Here is a screenshot even: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7axq.jpg